# How to host multiple Minecraft servers on the same IP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I just started a Minecraft server for me and one of my friend groups to use, but I'd also like a separate server for my other friends. I downloaded the server file again, made a new folder, did all the same things I had done to start up the first server, and I used [Port Map](https://www.codingmonkeys.de/portmap/) to create a new port.

I've heard you're supposed to log in to your router to do this. However, after looking up my IPv4 address online and entering it in my browser, nothing showed up. The port number I used with Port Map is 25566, as opposed to the first, which was 25565. To test if this server worked, I tried joining it my putting in my IP, adding a colon, and adding the new port, so it looked something like 111.222.333:25566. However, it didn't work. This is the method I had found online, though it wasn't a very detailed explanation, and I'd like to find a way to do this.

---

For KJBuilds, here's what's going on when I try to log in with my IP address. [image: Chrome error: This site can't be reached. 192.x.x.x refused to connect]

Answer (score 1):

Every router has a different way to log-in. Usually you have to attain your routers local IP-adress, which always looks like this: `192.168.X.0` or this: `192.168.X.1`
The X's are your network label. This is different for every home network and you just have to find out yours (usually it stands on the bottom of your router device, assuming you left it at the standard settings.)
When you arrive at the webpage of your router, you usually have to log-in with a username and a password, both of which you can find in the routers manual/on a sticker below the router device itself.

When you log-in, there should be an option called something like "assign ports" or "permit access", again, depending on your brand of home-router. But you can google that.
In that menu, you can look for the local IP of the device you're hosting your minecraft-gameserver on.

What you call an IP-adress is usually the so called IPv4 adress (There is also IPv6, but that is way different and not so common for private use). An IPv4 adress consists of 4 blocks of numbers ranging from `0-255`. So the lowest IP is `0.0.0.0` and the highest is `255.255.255.255`

There are **local IPs and public IPs**. Your **router** you have at home is your **gateway** to the internet. Everything on your side of the router is the so called **local area network (LAN)** or simply **"local network"**. It contains every device **in your home**, connected to the router. Then there is the **wide area network (WAN)** which is everything **behind your router**, outside of your home. You can basically see the internet as a WAN. So if you want to connect to a device inside your LAN with another device that also is located inside the LAN (everything connected to your router either via LAN-cable or W-LAN) you use the local IP of the device you want to go to. Local IPs always look like this: `192.168.X.X` (replace the Xs with numbers ranging from `0-255`.
If someone from outside wants to connect to a device inside your LAN, they have to go via your router, which has a public IP (a WAN IP) assigned to it. Devices from outside can't see your local IPs. They only see the public IP of the router. This one doesn't start with `192.168.`. The public IP your router gets, is dictated by your internet service provider (ISP) and may look something like this: `91.155.128.211`. Of course your numbers will be different. For most people every day a new public IP will be assigned, so you either have to tell everyone, every day what your public IP is (you can look it up at Google, typing "What is my IP". It will show you your current public IP, because as I mentioned before, outside devices, also the server of Google that looks up your IP, can only see your public one. Your local IPs are behind the router and the router protects everything in the LAN. It's private).
In your local IP your router will always have the ending 0 or 1, because that's the international convention, making sure everyone who sees an adress can say *"oh, its a zero/one. This device is a router!"*. This does not apply to your public IP, there the last number can vary, depending on the adress dictated by your service provider.

If someone connects from the outside now, they will have to connect to the router using its public IP. The job of the router is then, to divert incomming traffic to the right device in your LAN. That's where **ports** come in.

A port is basicaclly the highway towards a certain device or program the data is directed towards. So if your minecraft-server is running on `25565`, then your router has to direct all traffic for the server over port `25565`. If your running another minecraft-server on the same or another device, it has to have a different port, for example `25566`. Then you have to tell the router to divert all traffic for that server to port `25566`. You do this, by going to the "permit access" or "assign ports" (or whatever it's called for your router brand) menu in you router and tell it:

For the device `192.168.X.X` (your minecraft-server device) open ports `25565` and `25566` to the internet.

Usually you say:

For device `192.168.X.X` permit port `25565` through `25565`. Meaning you choose only one port for one server. And then there should be an option for "port requested outside" means you can also "map" a port to this device. Means you assign the device `192.168.X.X` the port `25565` but when someone connects to it from outside, you can tell the router to ask for another port, for example `10000`. But usually you just choose the same port you are giving to your server-device for outside. So under the option "port requested outside" also choose `25565`. Do the same for your second server.
If I understood that right, then you are running two servers on the same device. So to the same local IP, assign a second port with `25566` through `25566` and under "port requested outside" also choose `25566`.

Now the router will send all incoming traffic for the ports `25565` and `25566` to the device you have mentioned with its local IP `192.168.X.X`

Make sure to save the settings.

If someone wants to connect to you servers now, they have to know your public IP-adress (again you can look it up with Google "What is my IP") and the port. In your case `25565` and `25566`.

In minecraft server adress type (if `91.155.132.211` is your public IP):

`91.155.132.211:25565` or `91.155.132.211:25566`

for both servers.

There are different notations used for ports. Minecraft uses the one that separates the port from the IP with a colon.
So you always have `IP.IP.IP.IP:Port` (no spaces inbetween).

I hope this answer helps you with setting up your server. It does not directly answer your question with your router login, but since that is very unique to every router brand, you have to look it up in the manual anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Your public IP address is not the same as your router’s local address. If you open your powershell and enter the command `ipconfig` you should get a big dump of data with a bunch of internet-looking stuff there. Your router’s local IP (the one you should use in your browser) should be one that ends in a 0 or a 1.
Then just use whatever your details are to log in and look for a tutorial on port forwarding for your type of router.

By the end of that you should have at least two different open ports: `25565` and `25566`

In the Minecraft server config there will be a `port` value. Change this for the second server so it’s 25566 to match the open port on your router.
This should be all you need to do but tell me if I missed something

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I've checked out what my local IP address is, but it still won't work when I type it into my browser. Is it just an issue with my router? By the way, when I do change the port in the second server, will the people joining need to add the new port at the end of the server IP?

Comment: If you don’t mind, what is your router’s local IP? This isn’t sensitive information. Never give your public IP to the internet. Your local  IP should start with 192, 172, or 10.

Comment: Yes, my local IP starts with 192. Sorry, but I'm not sure I'm comfortable, even though I know it's probably safe, I just wouldn't like that information to be public. If I might ask, why do you need it?

Comment: I want to see if you’ve got something that looks like a router’s address, but it’s okay if you aren’t comfortable. Try removing the last cluster of numbers from your local IP and making it 0 instead? It’s hard to know what the problem is

Comment: Right, well if it's helpful, my IP looks like this

192.xxx.x.xx

Comment: I’d give this a try https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.techspot.com/amp/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/

Comment: @PaulStack https://www.techspot.com/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/ is the non-spyware version